# How to assign values based on an interval in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a value to a dataframe column based on a value that falls IN BETWEEN two values of an other dataframe:

```
intervals = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['From','To','Value'], data = [[0,100,'A'],[100,200,'B'],[200,500,'C']])
print('intervals\n',intervals,'\n')

points = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Point', 'Value'], data = [[45,'X'],[125,'X'],[145,'X'],[345,'X']])
print('points\n',points,'\n')

DesiredResult = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Point', 'Value'], data = [[45,'A'],[125,'B'],[145,'B'],[345,'C']])
print('DesiredResult\n',DesiredResult,'\n')
```

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's use `map`, first create a series using `pd.IntervalIndex` with `from_arrays` method:

```
intervals = intervals.set_index(pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(intervals['From'], 
                                                             intervals['To']))['Value']

points['Value'] = points['Point'].map(intervals)
```

Output:

```
   Point Value
0     45     A
1    125     B
2    145     B
3    345     C
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
def calculate_value(x):
    return intervals.loc[(x >= intervals['From']) & (x < intervals['To']), 'Value'].squeeze()

desired_result = points.copy()
desired_result['Value'] = desired_result['Point'].apply(calculate_value)
```